# Why is "$_" not expanded as expected by GNU make shell function?

Tags: shell, gnu-make

Consider the command `make --eval '$(error $(shell echo foo && echo $$_))'` (or equivalent makefile for make versions before 3.82 where eval option seems to have been added). I'd expect this to output "foo foo" and this is what happens with gmake 3.82.90 under Cygwin. But gmake 3.81 and 4.0 under Debian output "foo /usr/bin/make" instead.

Does anybody understand why does this happen?

Of course, in the real makefile the first part of the shell command is a bit more complicated than a simple echo and the idea was to output its argument only if the command was successful and leave it empty otherwise to indicate failure. This seemed more elegant than other alternatives to me and worked in initial testing (under Cygwin) but obviously I'd have to do something else now...

Comment: I see the same behaviour using `GNU Make 4.0` from the debian package but I **do not** see that with `GNU Make 4.0` built manually on CentOS 5. I get `foo foo` from the self-built version of CentOS.

Comment: Thanks for testing! This makes things even more... interesting. I checked [Debian patches](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/make) but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant there. Curiousier and curioisier indeed.

Comment: GNU Make 4.1 installed with `pacman` on Arch Linux also prints `foo foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shell issue not a make issue. Not sure why I didn't see that originally.

Debian

```
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo foo && echo $_'
foo
foo
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Nov  8 08:49 /bin/sh -> dash
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo foo && echo $_'
foo
/bin/sh
$ /bin/dash -c 'echo foo && echo $_'
foo
/bin/dash
```

CentOS

```
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo foo && echo $_'
foo
foo
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 29 10:39 /bin/sh -> bash
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo foo && echo $_'
foo
foo
```

So the issue here is an issue of when `$_` gets its non-startup value. And it would seem that dash and bash (in sh compatibility mode in newer versions of bash) agree that it shouldn't be set yet.

I don't know what the spec says about it.

Update: Some quick searching indicates that `$_` is a bash-ism in a number of ways (though the startup value seems to be a bit more widely portable). `$_` also just happens to be an incredibly confused variable as it can do a number of different things depending on context.

Comment: I should have said that I did think it was a shell issue initially but decided to omit it for brevity when asking the question because it seemed to me it wasn't: first, I use almost the same zsh under Cygwin and Debian (4.3). Second, bash does output `foo\nfoo` for me. But, and this is critical, `/bin/dash` does not and this indeed explains it as make turns out to always use `/bin/sh` (symlinked to dash under Debian) and not `SHELL` value. So... finally you're absolutely right, thanks!

Comment: You can set `SHELL` for make manually but it will not use an existing environment variable for it.